# What is the difference between ngPopup and uibmodal?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

ngpopup being mentioned here - https://github.com/MarkoCen/ngPopup

And uibmodal being the bootstrap modal

How are they different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [uibModal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) is one of official Bootstrap components written in pure AngularJS by the AngularUI Team.
- [ngPopup](https://github.com/MarkoCen/ngPopup) just a simple custom directive written by MarkoCen

Main difference in modal and modaless in ngPopup.

**uibModal** blocks your interface. It appears over page and it's elements. So it's modal.

**ngPopup** behaves similar to chat popup in facebook or somewhere else. It doesn't block page's interface and generally just has an absolute draggable position.

Comment: What does he mean by modalless for ngpopup?

Comment: @Tisha you have right question about modaless, it seems like to be crucial moment. I've edited my answer according to it.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed.

Comment: I cannot find anyone using ngpopup or a good example of it somehow. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

they are simply completely different implementations from different guys of a standard overlay / popup.
if you want to see which features each one has just check the corresponding documentations. i do like uibmodal, there's not much to complain about it though.

Comment: I see that uibmodal renders the parent page a little dim, is it possible to avoid that? ngpopup does not seem to be rendering the parent page dim (which I like and need) Also, not sure if uibmodal can be resized or dragged ?

Comment: I would try customize it. @Tisha I saw bootstrap modal made non-modal way samples in Google. ;) sorry, can't help you with it now.